# Desktop shortcut to open popup in Chrome (or another browser)

Tags: windows, popups, file-shortcut

I need a desktop shortcut (in the startup folder) to open a **popup** window (not a new window nor tab). 
The solution should be preferably in Chrome, but if there is none in Chrome, I would accept the solution in another browser. 
*It has to be a popup, not even just an Edge window doesn't work*

Popups generally look like this:

[image: Example with SoundCloud]

Comment: I have no idea what happened to my account (needed to create new with same credentials), but I can't add embedded images, editors feel free to change to change this.

Comment: Is there a way to replace the shortcut with shorty.htm and have it's content to open xyz.com in popup?